# PrimaryColor of Toolbar is Transparent on Resume

Tags: android, android-theme, android-toolbar

I have a strange probleme and i think it has something to do with the theme.

I structure my App in three parts: dashboard activity, list activity and detail activity. Each activity has the same theme. But after resuming from activity three is my Toolbar transparent and lost his primarycolor.

I can avoid this by copy the theme and rename it.

Has someone a solution for this?

```
<style name="TransAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dukes_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dukes_blue_statusbar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_amber_200</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/dukes_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dukes_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dukes_blue_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you share relevant code

Comment: I post my code tomorrow.

Comment: Do you animate the toolbar in your detail activity or some other place, setting / changing the color to transparent? Maybe some scrolling effect or animation?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Yes i animate my toolbar. Fading to transparent during scroll. But i don't reuse the same instance of Toolbar during my list and detail activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes i animate my toolbar. Fading to transparent during scroll. But i don't reuse the same instance of Toolbar during my list and detail activity

The reason for this behavior lies within animating the toolbars drawable, I had the same issue.

Due to the toolbars using the same style / theme, the color drawable of the toolbar gets cached. Modifying the toolbars color (animating it) will cause this *cached* color drawable instance to change and remain changed. The style is invalid, the color transparent, and this will also affect your parent activtiies. This is as much as I figured out.

You can easily change this by using a different drawable for your animated toolbar:

```
// mToolbar is the toolbar you are trying to animate
final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(background.getContext(), R.color.primary);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
    mToolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
} else {
    //noinspection deprecation
    mToolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
}
```

This will stop your animated version to reuse the same drawable and affecting your other activities.

Comment: Thank your for the tip. In check this out.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. I do mToolbar.setBackgroundDrawable( mToolbar.getBackgroundDrawable().mutate() );